# The element Person.UidDetails.TableKey is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Tags: sql-server, azure, symmetric-key

Need help with the error while exporting Data-tier application(bacpac file).

The element Person.UidDetails.TableKey is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Person.UidDetails.TableKey is nothing but a OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [Person.UidDetails.TableKey]. [image]

Error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Could not extract package from specified database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The element Person.UidDetails.TableKey is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Could I need help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY is not supported on Azure SQL Database.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/open-symmetric-key-transact-sql) for more details.

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative to it ? Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql

Comment: From the article `This feature is incompatible with database export using Data Tier Application Framework (DACFx). You must drop all symmetric keys before exporting.`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I have dropped both key and certificate ; replaced with password.